# How to use WebP in sass

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, webp

In my scss file I have:

```
.banner{
    background-image: url("/images/image.jpg");
}
```

Now I've converted this to a WebP image. I know that if it were an image inside html I should do:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="images/image.webp">
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="images/image.jpg">
    <img src="images/image.jpg">
</picture>
```

However, how to do something similar in a sass SCSS file? (I'm using Reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to detect webp support with CSS.

The best you are likely to be able to achieve is to use JavaScript to detect support and add a class to an element (e.g. with [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)). Since the `body` element is usually outside the scope of the elements modified by React, adding the class there with modernizr shouldn't be a problem.

Then you can use that class to pick which rule to use:

```
.banner{
    background-image: url("/images/image.jpg");
}

.webp .banner{
    background-image: url("/images/image.webp");
}
```